Python для Minecraft (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mcpi')

При запуске выдает
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mcpi'

Через pip устанавливали модуль - был результат, что все успешно установлено
КОД
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
mc = Minecraft.create()
mc.postToChat("Hi!")

ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ:
File "c:\Users\admin\Desktop\Minecraft\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mcpi'

Что сделать, чтобы запустилось корректно?
Последовательность запуска:

Запустили сервер Minecraft (Spigot)
Установили модуль mcpi (через pip install в консоли VSCode)
Запустили в VSCode через RunCode (правый верхний угол, иконка треугольничком)


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Установите модуль mcpi (через pip или другими средствами)

Пробовали, показывает что все успешно установлено, тем не менее программа как не работала, так и не работает

Здравствуйте, можете показать как вы запускаете программу и как установили пакет? (отредактировав вопрос)

«в консоли VSCode» — а запускаете-то через ту же самую консоль?

Да, все в одном окне

@andreymal Запуск происходит через VSCode, написали же.
@Павел Попробуйте python3 -m pip install mcpi, после python3 a.py, если python3 не найден используйте python

@ШвеевАлексей фраза «Запуск происходит через VSCode» слишком абстрактная, я прямо на скриншоте из вопроса вижу как минимум два способа запуска, один из которых может вполне не сработать

@andreymal под запуском "из вскод" я имею ввиду что используется билд система от вскода, которая просто вызывает файл через программу python через консоль (что видно на скрине).

@ШвеевАлексей а вот кстати там же видно две разные версии питона

@andreymal Ага, поэтому и попросил установить библиотеку и запустить программу через просто python3

В вашем случае VSCode использует другую версию python, а не ту, где вы устанавливаете вашу библиотеку.
Попробуйте выполнить команды:
python3 -m pip install mcpi
python3 a.py

В случае, если же команда python3 не найдена, замените команду python3 на python

Всем спасибо большое, кто старался помочь! Проблему решили, запустили:
pip install mcpi

через cmd.
Еще раз перезапустил, и все сработало, теперь сможет ребенок программировать!

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Предыдущий ответ идентичен вашему, если он решил вашу задачу, пожалуйста примите вопрос, нажав на зеленую галочку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1600171/264178 //ваш ответ необходимо [edit], если он отличен от имеющегося => как написать хороший ответ => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
